# Help on small data set with correlated features

Tags: multivariate-analysis, dataset

My data set is quite small and feature rich. It has 30 observations and 30 features/predictors. In addition to that, many features are correlated (often not linear). I have tried several things- Random Forest, Naive Bayes, PCA for data reduction, checked out both linear & ranked based correlations etc....but the best classification accuracy I've achieved so far is only 50% using random forest.

Any suggestion regarding what else to try will be highly appreciated! Many thanks.

Problem Description-

The problem is to build an approximate predictor system that is able to roughly predict the Oil  Production of a well (target variable), based on the predictors (like well depth, trajectory, rock brittleness, mineral content etc).

Comment: 30 is pretty small... There's no way to gather more data? Also, what do you mean by: "they all are required to be combined together to predict oil production"? Since your dataset is so small you could post the **csv** file or whatever somewhere--it might be more helpful... Also, what software are you using?

Comment: Well, since your current results are about as good as a coin flip, I don't see how you could be any worse off with the 80... Also, it would help if you try to translate your question into less field-specific terms because those can often deter would-be answerers. Lastly, how is this a classification problem?

Comment: No, I didn't mean to *delete* what you had--actually, it was kind of interesting and did add to the post.

Comment: I am trying to build a predictor system , so that given similar set of predictors I am able to predict the production of my sample well (or broadly in which class it will fall making it a classification problem).

Comment: One obvious thing that I tried was to assign weights to these predictors based on their impact on the target variable, keeping in mind their correlations with one another. I have been using WEKA & Salford. One ranker algorithm I used (InfoGainEval  of Weka) is assigning almost all of the weight to the top predictor while aprox. zero to the rest, which makes no sense. 

Since I don't know which initial model to propose for polynomial regression, as 30 interdependent features can lead to many possible options, I have not been able to use regression too.