# Pattern mining on a small data set

Tags: multicollinearity, small-sample, pattern-recognition, nonlinear

I have a small data set 30 features/predictors and 30 observations. My target variable is Oil production and my predictors are well & reservoir properties (depth, trajectory, temperature, pressure etc) I want to identify the manner in which these features impact the target variable via identifying patterns that may exist in my dataset. The relationships may be non-linear and many features are correlated to each other.

Can you please suggest me some great ways to approach this problem?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You've already asked this question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109633/help-on-small-data-set-with-correlated-features. You created an entirely new account just so you could ask it again??

Comment: Here are some issues: 1.) Your dataset is too small 2.) Your number of features is too large considering your sample size 3.) This issue is *highly* idiosyncratic--it has less to do with Statistics and more to do with the specifics of your field (i.e. geology/oil production) 4.)You have no idea about the functional form of the underlying relationship. 5.) Along with **multicollinearity** you should probably be worried about **endogeneity** (but I may be wrong since I don't know *anything* about geology and oil production...).

Comment: Offcourse I did not create new account for this question. I had problems with accessing and resetting my password.

Comment: I seriously don't think this a idiosyncratic issue, though like any other data set in data sciences it does come from a specific field.

I am well aware of the issues, which is precisely why I posted this question for some suggestions to tackle these issues.

Comment: As an aside, if you post a link to a **csv** file with your data (you could even post the data on **GitHub**) you might get more responses since it will give us something to work with...

Comment: Yo, Batool, maybe this dataset is something you could look at as an alternative to the limited dataset you're currently looking at? http://www.ihs.com/products/oil-gas/ep-data/well/united-states.aspx

Comment: @SteveS, thanks! I have started working on collecting more data. Since this is not an easy task, I wanted to check if there was anything else that I could do on my current data set (that I have not already tried) before proceeding with data collection.

Comment: I wish I could post the csv, but much of the data in Oil & Gas industry is confidential.

Comment: Thanks @BrashEquilibrium! Yes I know this website along with a couple more websites are out there but the information they offer is not free. You need to pay a certain amount per well. –

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some strategies that may help you:

1. Try `glmnet`, a user-friendly R package that implements elastic-net-penalized regression. In tuning the hyperparameters, you might be best off using leave-one-out cross-validation because your small sample size is so small. I suggest `glmnet` because it can handle $p\gg n$ cases where you have more predictors than observations. You could try this procedure using as many orders of interaction as your RAM can handle.
2. Variable reduction strategies like Principle Components Analysis (choosing the components that explain, say 85-95% of the variance) may help, as well. Then again, every single time I have tried variable reduction strategies in $p\gg n$ cases, it hasn't reduced the parameter space that much, and once I found out about regularized regression I've depended even less on this. When using variable reduction, maybe focus on subsets of the variables that show high multicollinearity. If you find yourself in the happy situation whether you've reduced your predictor set to something quite small. Still, you may have separation or quasi-separation in your data, so maybe still go with `glmnet` for regularization, or a Bayesian regularization method as implemented in R package `bayesglm`.
3. Use subject matter experts to create a set of alternative models containing more reasonable subsets of the predictors, and which actually use scientific theory to arrive at the functional relationships between the smaller subset of predictors and the response. Use Bayesian model averaging to combine these models together into a single predictive model. If you don't end up using all 30 features, who cares so long as you have improved prediction substantially beyond a coin flip? Sometimes, the machine learning approach isn't the right one. When you have a very small data set, and you're trying to reduce the dimensionality as much as possible, well, that's pretty much the anti-machine-learning-big-data-type use case.
4. Collect more data.

Comment: Even *good* advice can be *bad* when it's applied to the wrong situation. Tell me: What do you think the odds are that following 1-3 *exactly* with *this* dataset will produce **Statistically valid** results?

Comment: The odds are low, but the person asked for advice given what they've got, and this is what I believe to be the best advice. It also includes your advice (collect more data), although you went into that strategy in further detail.

Comment: I was holding out on up-voting your answer since I figured it'd end up with more votes anyway... But now you have me feeling all guilty and stuff...

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium! That was very informative! Many thanks! Yes PCA is what I had begun with. Logistic regression after PCA gave poor results, but perhaps I should also try regression with LASSO. The whole purpose of posting this question was to check out if there is anything else that I should try (apart from several things I have already tried), before proceeding with further data collection. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, try regularized regression. But we're serious, you've got very little data, so proceed with extreme caution.

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium , I tried glmnet on 30 observations to begin with, my alpha=0.5 and I varied the number of folds. Upon getting the coefficients of the fit, I plotted a cross plot of the model's predicted production (response variable) versus the actual production data. The correlation coefficient turned out to be around 0.80, which is great! However, what I am confused with is the Mean Squared Error on the cross validation data set (cv.glmnet) which is about 60%. When the correlation is so high, should the MSE not be low?

Comment: First question: what did you set the family parameter to?
Second question: when you cross plotted the model's prediction, did you correlate the predicted production in the *test* sets versus the actual production data, or did you just look at the training error?
Third question: would you remind me of what kind of target variable you're look at and how you transformed it, if at all?

Comment: First Ans- I used the default family (Gaussian).
Second Ans- While cross plotting, I used the actual production data from all the 30 observations vs the model prediction, which was obtained by extracting the coefficients calculated using glmnet, forming an equation and using it to predict the respponse variable.

y=B1*X1 +B2^X2.....

As usual, here "y" is the the response variable (Production), B1,B2..are the coefficients and X1,X2 the predictor variables.

3) I have normalized the entire data set. My target variable (oil production) was continuous previously. It too has been normalized.

Comment: Here is the  code

cv=cv.glmnet(x,y, standardize = FALSE, maxit=1000000000000000,  alpha=0.5, k=10);

I used 'standardize = false' because I had normalized the data beforehand.

Comment: I tried several "k" values.

Comment: Next question, is the error measure the raw MSE or the *root* MSE?

Comment: It is raw MSE..

Comment: Okay, so what is probably going on is that the cross-correlation you ran is within-test-sample error, and the MSE is cross-validation error. Just look at the cross-validation error. You have a lot of work to do tuning the alpha and lambda regularization parameters. Also, for the k-values, remember my suggestion to do LOOCV, so k should equal your sample size. Honestly, though, it will be difficult to tune your regularization parameters since there will be so much uncertainty in the cross-validation scores due to your small sample size.

Answer (score 4):

## **Get more data**.

This is probably not the answer you're looking for but there's nothing else to tell you. Frankly, you currently don't even have enough data for a *test set*. [*Are there really no resources online that have similar datasets you can (freely) use??*]

Sure, someone may come along and suggest you try some fancy **bootstrapping** technique but, frankly, I really think you're best served by scouring the internet for some more data you can use (even if you don't end up using this data in your final analysis, additional data could still *indirectly* help you a lot by suggesting a functional form for your analysis).

Good luck!

Comment: It is not necessary to have one test set. If you use LOOCV you can use ALL of your data as the test set. Sure it is still not ideal have only 30 observations, but it is still not completely hopeless building a predictive model in this case.

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium: The "test set" part wasn't the point of my answer. Nevertheless, point taken...

Comment: Maybe not "hopeless"... but also not *too far* from it...

Comment: LOL. It just seems like this is freaking geology and there has got to be some good expert model or set of expert models out there that could inform the structure of some simple models that could then be averaged based on their Bayes factors or CV scores.

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium: Maybe. Like I said earlier, I know squat about Geology. I guess I was thinking *exactly the opposite way*: Companies like **Exxon-Mobile** employ huge *supercomputers* investigating this stuff (in all fairness, this may be more so for exploratory purposes and less for already-established wells, but still...). Plus, whether or not a company extracts the oil vs. leaving it in the ground has to do with a lot of other things, too, like the price of Crude (I bet that's not one of the **30** predictors!)

Comment: My guess is that data is far from open access. :-)

Comment: Well, maybe I type too soon, there is this: http://www.ihs.com/products/oil-gas/ep-data/well/united-states.aspx

Comment: In short, yeah, you've definitely got a point about collecting more data, and I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Are you telling me that Batool didn't even try googling this stuff?!

Comment: I suppose not. I'm glad I know it's out there, though. Maybe I'll go machine-learning-tastic on this dataset.

Comment: Well, offcourse I did. As stated above, the info in this website is not given out for free.

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium: "this is freaking geology" -- I just thought about that line again and it made me laugh.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.math-gnostics.com/index.php?a=introduction
Forget the old Gauss and his models on small datasets. This one is possible the best solution. It will provide you with a continuous empirical distribution model (passing all Goodness-of-Fit tests ex. Komolgorov-Smirnov) even on small sets of data.
I haven't talked to Kovanic (he must be old man now) for years but I have worked with his older SW for years and it is more like miracle than statistical method.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this interesting and little-known approach to our attention.

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately this guy is more NERD than marketing guru so unfortunately it is not that famous as (I believe) it should be. I have seen several use cases that proved not only the concept but the whole product. Im not aware of current SW package I used the ancient one for W3.11 in nineties ;)

Comment: I confess that this sounds a little too good to be true. But I'll have to read about it further to be sure!

Comment: @SkiperSkiprovic, quite interesting! Let me do some more reading on  it. Thanks!

Comment: Just curious: Has any of this work been peer-reviewed?

Comment: @Steve-S Kovanic is oldschool member of Czech Academy of Science. The "Gnostic theory of uncertain data" (the proper name) was the core of his D.Sc. habilitation. What I remember he is physicist by nature so the Gnostic theory is not "just another formula" it incorporates stuff like total energy of sample space, its entropy, etc. I was just the humble user. I did not have access to the core nor the source but I had enough time to play with it and it was "too good to be true" ;)

Comment: @SkiperSkiprovic , I am finding it hard to understand how to use the code. The book mentioned on the website is very detailed. I am new to R programming. Do you have any quick user guide or anything else for the code?

Comment: @Batool I'm not able to help you, I have no experience with R either. I was just using very ancient Windows 3.x version in nineties. During the decades my career has brought me far away from statistics of any kind. I have just noticed a "small data set question" so I googled the internet to find out what has happened with the Gnostics and potentially point someone attention there. If there is a point of contact on Gnostic page you have to ask for assistance there. Sorry

Comment: For those who would like to access math-gnostics.com as of 2014, [here's a snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20141217230610/http://math-gnostics.com/).